# Why is my merged dictionary only returning the last value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I merged two dictionaries together and am only able to print the last item of the new, merged dictionary.

I am using a `for loop` that combines one dictionary with the other but it appears each loop is overwriting the previous one. How can I print out all, 45,000 iterations, and not just the last one? Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
import json

Empty = None
read = 'Data_old.json' #source json file
write = 'Data_new.json' #new, target location for updated objects

with open(read, "r") as file: #retrieve json file, to read
        data = json.load(file) 

objLen = len(data['features']) #define loop count
obj={} #create empty dict variable for merged dictionaries

i=0
while i < objLen: #create loop
    temp = data['features'][i]  #define where to place new dict
    origStr = data['features'][i]['properties']['GAZETTED_NAME'] #define value location
    i+=1
    if waterbody is not Empty:    #by-pass Nonetype errors
        newStr = waterbody.title()     #format value in GAZETTED_NAME column
        newDict = {'waterbody': newStr}    #create dict & assign new values to key 
        temp.update(newDict)       #update target object with new dict
        obj.update(temp)       #capture all updates in empty list
    else:
        newStr = "0"                  #by-pass Nonetype errors
        newDict = {'waterbody': newStr}   #assign new value to keys
        temp.update(newDict)       #update target object with new dict
        obj.update(temp)       #capture all updates in empty list

print(obj) #only returns last object in dictionary
```

With no sucess, I've also tried creating a copy of the empty dictionary as so:

```
obj={} #create variable for empty dict
dest = obj.copy()


temp.update(newStr)       #update target object with new dict
dest.update(temp)      #capture all updates in empty list

print(obj)
```

This prints out an empty dictionary: {}

Sample Data - Data_old.json (1 of 45,000 objects):

```
    { 
"features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "coordinates" : [ -119.18892336714474, 50.085088152701054 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "GAZETTED_NAME" : "LOST LAKE",
            }
        }
```

Current Output (only the very last object, based on the source data):

```
    {
    'type': 'Feature', 
    'geometry': { 
        'coordinates': [-118.53304142063604, 50.073811324914224]
    }, 
    'properties': {
       'GAZETTED_NAME': 'LAST OBJECT'
    }, 
    'waterbody': 'Last Object'}
```

Desired Output (all 45,000 objects):

```
 {
    'type': 'Feature', 
    'geometry': { 
        'coordinates': [-118.53304142063604, 50.073811324914224]
    }, 
    'properties': {
       'GAZETTED_NAME': 'FIRST OBJECT'
    }, 
    'waterbody': 'First Object'},

 {
    'type': 'Feature', 
    'geometry': { 
        'coordinates': [-118.53304142063604, 50.073811324914224]
    }, 
    'properties': {
       'GAZETTED_NAME': 'SECOND OBJECT'
    }, 
    'waterbody': 'Second Object'},
  

   ...


  {
    'type': 'Feature', 
    'geometry': { 
        'coordinates': [-118.53304142063604, 50.073811324914224]
    }, 
    'properties': {
       'GAZETTED_NAME': 'LAST OBJECT'
    }, 
    'waterbody': 'Last Object'},
```

Comment: Could you share some sample data and expected output as well to test.

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave actual data.  We have no idea what `data['features']` contains, or even what type it is.

Comment: @JohnGordon data['features'] references a json array, "features", that has a large number of sub-objects. I've included sample source data in the original post; trimmed for simplicity.

Comment: `obj` is a single dict.  But your desired output seems to be list of dicts...

Comment: @JohnGordon apologies, my original question was misleading -- `obj` is the sum of two dictionaries. I have already combined the two dictionaries and am trying to print out every iteration, not just the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've defined what the variable waterbody is. Maybe you mean to use `data['features'][i]['waterbody']` instead of `waterbody`? If this is the case you can just see if the key exists in the dictionary, i.e.:

```
if 'waterbody' in data['features'][i]:
   waterbody = data['features'][i]['waterbody']
   newStr = waterbody.title()     #create new value
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I believe the issue has to do with the `for loop`. It appears each loop is overwriting the previous loop in the empty `obj` dictionary.